# How can I create a spring-boot application which can be easily extended with plugins?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am planning a spring boot application that can be extended with plugins. However, I haven't found out yet whether spring boot meets my requirements in this regard.

I imagine the following folder structure:

- application

  - core                     <-- core jars

    - main_application.jar
    - ...
  - plugins

    - PluginTypA           <-- pluginTypA jars
    - PluginTypB           <-- pluginTypB jars
    - PluginTypC           <-- pluginTypC jars
    - ...
  - ...

Does Spring Boot provide a way for the core application to automatically detect and load these plugins? How can I get the annotated classes of my plugins to be included in the ApplicationContext of the core application?

Update:
When I develop the core application, I don't know which plugins are developed in future and which package name they will have. So the core application has to get known about the plugins on runtime or startup and add the Components to the ApplicationContext.

Example:
My coreApplication provides a plugin type for importing data. Actual there is just the need to import .csv files. In one year i get the requirement to import .xlsx files. I don't want to update the whole application, i just want to write a plugin, package it and then copy it to the folder of the plugin type and restart my core application.

Comment: The `@ComponentScan` annotation might be what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679581/how-to-make-springs-componentscan-search-components-in-included-jars

Comment: I'am not sure, if this is what I'am searching for. When I develop the core application, I don't know which plugins are developed in future and which package name they will have. So the core application has to get known about the plugins on runtime or startup and add the Components to the ApplicationContext.

Comment: You mean something like this: https://blog.frankel.ch/java-service-loader-vs-spring-factories/ ?

Comment: Spring boot has a feature called "AutoConfigurarion" which works very similar to ServiceLoader. Should be exactly what you are looking for. Jars must be on the classpath, though

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I think a mixture of all answers is what I was looking for. After trying it out I will give response.